# Attempting to scrape for PDF documents (unsuccessfully)

Tags: pdf, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapely

I am trying to scrape a website (obr.uk) for all of the PDF files so that I can save them to my computer. To do this at the moment I am currently using 'Outwit Docs' which doesn't seem to be going too well; with it not recognizing some pages as having links to PDF documents amongst other things. Is there another easy (ish) solution to this?

I don't know too much about scraping but can't seem to find any fairly easy solutions to this.

Comment: [Here is one option](https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Apdf+site%3Aobr.uk).

Comment: Thanks! missed this. Must say that outwit isn't great at collected these scraped google links though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "website downloader" tools such :

- httrack : https://www.httrack.com/page/1/en/index.html
- "wget" linux command line

and filter the downloads by "filetype" pdf

You can find lists of tools here :

- https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-do-i-download-an-entire-website-for-offline-reading/
- https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/windows-offline-browsers/